# Knockoutjs - Pass observable value to another function?

Tags: knockout.js

I am loading my viewmodel using the return pattern. My VM has a observable called 'intro'.

I want to pass the  value of the 'intro' observable to another script on my page.

In my code below how do I set the value of twtTitle to the 'intro' observable value?

Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var twtTitle = my.intro.value;
      var twtUrl = location.href;
      var maxLength = 140 - (twtUrl.length + 1);
      if (twtTitle.length > maxLength) {
          twtTitle = twtTitle.substr(0, (maxLength - 3)) + '...';
      }
      var twtLink = 'http://twitter.com/home?status=' 
                  + encodeURIComponent(twtTitle + ' ' + twtUrl);
      document.write
      (
         '<a href="' + twtLink + '" target="_blank"' + '>' + 
         '<img src="/Images/tweetthis.gif"  border="0" alt="Tweet This!" /' + 
         '><' + '/a>'
      );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a Event aggregator pattern? I have made one for my SignalR Eventaggregator library
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy

If you have no need for SignalR you can extract the relefvant client side Event Aggregator code, see this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jh8JV/

For your specific useage you could do

```
this.intro = ko.observable();
this.intro.subscribe(function(value) {
   signalR.eventAggregator.publish(new MyApp.IntroChanged(value));
}, this);
```

The benefits of this pattern is decoupling, stronly typed messages and high extensibility.